# Condition for stability of the tower

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

We have a tower made of $N$ blocks. With each new turn, tower can lose $N_1$ blocks with probability $p_1$, lose $N_2$ blocks with probability $p_2$, lose all the blocks it has with probability $p_3$, or don't lose any blocks at all. Also, each turn, $A$ blocks are added (if needed, because the tower can't have more than $N$ blocks). Tower is considered stable if it has $B$ or more blocks for 80% of time. We need to find $A$.

Solving reccurence relation
$$S(1)=N$$
$$S(n)=(1-p_3)*S(n-1)+A-p_1N_1-p_2N_2$$

gives

[image]

Thus as n goes to infinity, 
$$S(n)→(A-p_1N_1-p_2N_2)/p_3$$
Then the tower is stable if 
$$A⩾p_3*B+p_1*N_1+p_2*N_2$$

Is it correct? I feel like something is wrong because I didn't use the fact that the tower can't have more than $N$ or less than 0 blocks.

[edited]: I've tried to use Markov chain, but now I have problems with interpreting the results. Here I have 5 states:

1. the tower has $N$ blocks
2. the tower loses $N_1$ blocks and gains $A$ blocks
3. the tower loses $N_2$ blocks and gains $A$ blocks
4. has lost all the blocks
5. gains $A$ blocks

   [image]

Seems like my equilibrium state is [1 1 1 1 1], those with the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want "stable" to mean? If you mean that you want to stay above $B$ forever from some time onwards, that can't happen, because at every turn you have a positive probability $p_3$ of jumping back to $0$. On the other hand, if you just want to get above $B$ once, that will inevitably happen for any $A\geq 1$; in fact you will get above $B$ infinitely often.

Comment: @JamesMartin, it means that I want to stay above B blocks, say, for 80% of time or so.

Comment: OK. In that case the 80% (or whatever you want) is going to have to figure in your solution.

Comment: You can model your system as a "Markov chain" and for given values of the parameters $N, N_1, N_2, p_1, p_2, p_3, A$ you could calculate its "equilibrium distribution". You want that equilibrium distribution to put some proportion $r$ (=80%, say) of its mass above the level $B$. But unfortunately it's unlikely that there'll be a nice general formula for the $A$ that you need as a function of $N, N_1, p_1, p_2, p_3, B, r$.

Comment: @JamesMartin, thank you for the idea, but I'm unfamiliar with Markov chains. Could you recommend me a textbook?